# Shapely MultiPolygon Construction will not accept entire set of Polygons

Tags: polygon-creation, shapely

I am new to Shapely, so I am using a work request to learn a bit more about it.  I need to execute a number of unions to build larger geometries from [assessment neighborhoods](http://dcatlas.dcgis.dc.gov/metadata/AsNbhdPly.html) in DC.  I am curious about why a MultiPolygon does not seem to be able to be constructed from a list unless it's sliced (or why what I am doing is incorrect).  More importantly, I cannot seem to get all of my polygons in there.  Here is the set up.

```py
#Open assessment neighborhood shapefile
asmt=fiona.open(data_dir+'ASNBHDPLY.shp')

#Initiate iterator
nbhd=asmt.next()

#Create container for features
nbhd_list=[]

#For each feature...
for nbhd in asmt:
    #...throw the feature in the list
    nbhd_list.append(shape(nbhd['geometry']))
```

From here, I attempted to generate a MultiPolygon object with both of the following choices.

```
nbhds=MultiPolygon(nbhd_list)
```

and

```
nbhds = MultiPolygon([shape(nbhd['geometry']) for nbhd in asmt])
```

The second version was tried because of the success of the technique [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70591/creating-shapely-multipolygons-from-shape-file-multipolygons).

In both cases, an exception was thrown:

```
NotImplementedError: A polygon does not itself provide the array interface. Its rings do.
```

I did note, however, that both the following approaches worked:

```
nbhds=MultiPolygon([nbhd_list[0],nbhd_list[1]])
```

and

```
nbhds=MultiPolygon(nbhd_list[:62])
```

The kicker, however, is that there are 71 assessment neighborhoods and I get the above error as soon as I exceed 62.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was not with the read in of the data.  For some reason, two of the **Polygon** objects were read in as a single **MultiPolygon** object.  Whether or not this is an issue with Shapely or the input file is not altogether clear.  The resolution was to just extract and bust up the **MP**.  The **Polygon** object components were just appended to the original list.  So, just in case anyone else encounters this issue, validation is your friend.

Answer (score 5):

look at [Creating Shapely MultiPolygons from shape file MultiPolygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70591/creating-shapely-multipolygons-from-shape-file-multipolygons/70608#70608) and I detail below the process:

1) browse through the shapefile :

- with next()

```py
import fiona
c = fiona.open('polygons.shp')
# the result is a Python iterator, so to read the first feature of the shapefile
print c.next()
# the result is a Python dictionary (GeoJSON)format
{'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(249744.23153029341, 142798.16434689672), (250113.79108725351, 142132.95714436853), (250062.62130244367, 141973.76225829343), (249607.77877080048, 141757.71205576291), (249367.77424759799, 142304.68402918623), (249367.77424759799, 142304.68402918623), (249744.23153029341, 142798.16434689672)]]}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'id', 1), (u'couleur', 1), (u'id_class', None)])}
# if you want the geometry only
print c.next()['geometry']
{'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[(249175.78991730965, 142292.53526406409), (249367.77424759799, 142304.68402918623), (249607.77877080048, 141757.71205576291), (249014.45396077307, 141876.13484290778), (249175.78991730965, 142292.53526406409)]]}
....
```

but as all the iterators, this method raises a built-in StopIteration exception at the end of the iterator or end of the file:

```py
c.next()
Traceback (most recent call last): .....   
StopIteration
```

- so the solution is a list (iterator without the StopIteration exception)

```py
c = fiona.open('polygons.shp')
features = list(c)
# and the result is a list of all the features in the shapefile:
# or
for features in fiona.open('polygons.shp'):
     ....
```

2) Therefore to convert the polygons to a multipolygon:

```py
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygo
multi = []
# append the geometries to the list
for pol in fiona.open('polygons.shp'):
    multi.append(shape(pol['geometry'])
# create the MultiPolygon from the list of Polygons
Multi = MultiPolygon(multi)
print Multi.wkt
'MULTIPOLYGON (((249744.2315302934148349 142798.1643468967231456, 250113.7910872535139788 142132.9571443685272243, ..., 249870.8182051893090829 142570.3083320840960369)))'
```

Or in one line with a list comprehension:

```py
Multi = MultiPolygon([shape(pol['geometry']) for pol in fiona.open('polygons.shp')]
```

Note:

If there are different types of geometries in the shapefile (MultiPolygon embedded in polygons)  use [unary_union](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union): "the unary union function can operate on different geometry types, not only polygons as is the case for the older cascaded unions"

```py
from shapely.ops import unary_union
polygon1 = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0)])
polygon2 = Polygon([(1, 1), (2,2), (2, 0)])
poly  = MultiPolygon([polygon1,polygon2])
list = [polygon1,polygon2,poly]
result = unary_union(list)
print result
MULTIPOLYGON (((0.00 0.00, 1.00 1.00, 1.00 0.00, 0.00 0.00)), ((1.00 1.00, 2.00 2.00, 2.00 0.00, 1.0 1.00)))
```

So:

```py
geoms =[shape(feature['geometry']) for feature in fiona.open("polygons.shp")]
result = unary_union(geoms)
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond, and the mapping business will be helpful as well.  However, I am afraid I already linked to your earlier response in my question.  The proposed technique, while effective generally, was not applicable to my situation.  The problem was a single MultiPolygon was embedded amongst the Polygon objects.

Comment: see my new note in the answer.

Comment: Now that is good to know!  A quick follow up: I have been working on creating unions across specific neighborhoods so that we can identify sub-District regions.  I was going to try and do this by matching indices across lists (one list of neighborhood names, and one list of neighborhood Polygon objects).  Is there a more efficient way of going about such a task?  The groups are basically chosen by visual reference.

Comment: For this, try  [rtree](http://toblerity.org/rtree/index.html) with shapely.

Comment: Well this does look useful.  I'll have to dive in on this material.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

Thank to Marvin's answer. I had the same problem. So based on the hint, I rewrite the code to check if there is any case a shape(...) call lead to the creation of a MultiPolygon. Then this works perfectly.

```
polys = []
for pol in fiona.open(shapefile):
    poly = shape(pol['geometry'])
    if isinstance(poly, MultiPolygon):
        polys += poly
    else:
        polys.append(poly)
mp = MultiPolygon(polys)
```